# Tool to compare two source code files on Windows

Tags: source-code, code-analysis

Are there any gratis tools to help me compare the differences between two source code files? (for Python, and C++）on Windows 10?

Comment: Do you mean morse code? If not, please explain in greater detail 1) What kind of code 2) On what operating system. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoulN，sorry, I am first to ask question in the community and I am not good at English grammar.

Comment: Should it be gratis? If yes, please edit your question to say it. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "similarities"? Code changes (i.e. you're looking for a diff tool like WinDiff or Meld), coding style, used algorithms/components, …?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my answer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/60824/open-source-c-code-comparison-tool/60869#60869) - ***two days ago*** HINT: you can search our site for questions similar to the one that you plan to ask.

I don’t think that you will get a better open source application than [WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/?lang=en)  (although it would do no harm to look at [Kdiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/).

Neither of them will handle your `int i; for (i ...) -> for (int i ...)` example, but they are open source, so you might give it a try, or request the feature from the author.

[image]

General
•   Supports Microsoft Windows XP or newer
•   Handles Windows, Unix and Mac text file formats
•   Unicode support
•   Tabbed interface

File Compare
•   3-way File Comparison New!
•   Visual differencing and merging of text files
•   Flexible editor with syntax highlighting, line numbers and word-wrap
•   Highlights differences inside lines                         <= ============================================
•   Difference pane shows current difference in two vertical panes
•   Location pane shows map of files compared
•   Moved lines detection

Folder Compare
•   Regular Expression based file filters allow excluding and including items
•   Fast compare using file sizes and dates
•   Compares one folder or includes all subfolders
•   Can show folder compare results in a tree-style view
•   3-way Folder Comparison Work in progress

Image Compare New!
•   Support many types of images
•   Can highlight the differences with blocks
•   Overlaying of the pictures is possible
Version Control
•   Creates patch files (Normal-, Context- and Unified formats)
•   Resolve conflict files

Other
•   Shell Integration (supports 64-bit Windows versions)
•   Archive file support using 7-Zip
•   Plugin support
•   Localizable interface
•   Online manual and installed HTML Help manual

Comment: Happy user of KDiff here (well, I'd be happier on a Linux workstation but ...) glad to see it mentioned

Comment: Kidiff - it's not just for Linux any more :-)

Answer (score 2):

**[CudaText](http://uvviewsoft.com/)** editor is gratis. It has plugin "[Differ](https://github.com/OlehL/cuda_differ)", it can be installed from "Plugins - Addon Manager - Install". To call plugin, use "Plugins - Differ" menu.

[image: Differ plugin in action]

Answer (score 0):

There are many good choices for this kind of software. What I'm using on Windows these days is [**Diffinity**](http://www.truehumandesign.se/s_diffinity.php). It's gratis (though not open source) and has most of the typical diff tool features people have come to expect. It does folder comparison but not three-way comparison.

One thing I think it does better than most other choices (such as [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/)) is the Explorer integration. Notice that you can right-click on each file you want to compare and set it as the left or right, respectively:

[image: Diffinity Explorer integration]

Once you've selected both left and right in this manner, Diffinity will launch automatically with those selections. As far as I can tell, the context-menu choice for WinMerge only lets you do this for the left file; you still have to select the other one using other means.

Diffinity also uses the visual style where the added or deleted lines are "funnel-highlighted" (like [Meld](https://meldmerge.org/)), rather than padding one side or the other with empty lines (like WinMerge):

[image: Diffinity sample screenshot from product Web site]

Whether funneling or padding is better is of course subjective. I prefer Diffinity's highlighting over Meld's (because I find the thick, black arrows in Meld neither attractive nor useful).